Compute basis of the intersection of two integer lattices
I am trying to implement an algorithm that gets as an input the bases of two integer lattices $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ and outputs a basis of the intersection. In https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi10/cse206a/lec2.pdf it says that we first need to compute the dual bases $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$, then compute $H=HNF([D_{1}| D_{2}])$ and then find the dual $H'$.
Given a lattice basis $B$, the dual $D$ can be found by computing $D = B \left( B^T B \right)^{-1}$.
My problem is at the step of computing the dual basis which involves one matrix inversion and the entries of $D_{1}, D_{2}, H'$ become non-integers. I don't know what i can do to output an integer basis.
Edit: To be more specific of where i am having trouble i will give an example. Let's assume that we have the lattice basis (the vectors are the columns):
$B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
$.
Following the steps to find the dual basis:

Compute: $B^TB=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 7 \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 7 \\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 9 \\ 9 & 50 \\ \end{bmatrix} $
Compute: $(B^TB)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 9 \\ 9 & 50 \\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{50}{169} & -\frac{9}{169} \\ -\frac{9}{169} & \frac{5}{169} \\ \end{bmatrix}$
Compute: $B(B^TB)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 7 \\ \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}\frac{50}{169} & -\frac{9}{169} \\ -\frac{9}{169} & \frac{5}{169} \\ \end{bmatrix}$

In step 2, i get a matrix with non-integer values, so in step 3 the matrix has also non-integers and it goes on until $H'$ (final steps). I am very new to lattice theory and i don't know how to handle my computations to get a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$. Or i don't know if i am missing something in theory.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560411/basis-for-the-intersection-of-two-integer-lattices

Hello @gem1100 and welcome to stackexhange. It might be useful to include a concrete numerical example of B1, B2 and the D matrices you have calculated in the post.

Hello @Heterotic and thank you for the reply. I did edit my answer to be more specific. I really hope it helps.

I haven't looked at this in a long time, but the first thing to try is to pull the 1/169 factor out of the hnf form and do hnf of the integer matrix. You then proceed according to the algorithm. Because you will have to do dual again at the end, I have a feeling that these factors will disappear.

I think you are right. If in step 2 i pull the 1/169 factor out of my calculations and then add it back, i get integer results. A good example is how the dual_lattice() function in sagemath works.
